# Local sharing between Netgear router and modem

Tags: router, network-share, bridge, modem, netgear

We have 2 internet (Broadband) connection,

About connection 1

- ADSL modem (Binatone) + Netgear wireless router (Netgear WGR614-v10)
- ADSL Modem (192.168.1.0) , Wireless router (192.168.2.0)

About Connection 2

- ADSL wireless modem router (Netgear DG8345-v5) 192.168.0.0

Need:

Want to connect both wireless router/modem for local file sharing, How can i do this ?

Comment: What are your netmasks?

Comment: @Cocoabean 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both routers support RIP you should be able to just enable it and connect their LAN segments together with a crossover cable. If you don't have RIP you will have to create static routes so that traffic from 2.0/24 destined to 0.0/24 is directed to 0.0 to be routed. You would also have to add a route telling 0.0/24 to send traffic destined to 0.2/24 network to the 0.2 router. A page on your WebGUIs will probably ask for "Destination" (the network of the other router: ie. 192.168.0.0/24 on Connection 1's router), and Gateway is of course the ip of the other router (192.168.0.0 for Connection 1).